# Passing Parameters with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, parameters, httpurlconnection, basicnamevaluepair

With the old Apache stuff deprecated in API 22, I am finally getting around to updating my network stuff.

Using `openConnection()` seems pretty straight forward.  However, I have not seen any good example to send parameters with it.

How would I update this code?

```
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",String.valueOf(userId)));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
```

Now that `NameValuePair` and `BasicNameValuePair` are also deprecated.

EDIT:  My server side `php` code doesn't expect JSON parameters and I can't all of the sudden switch due to existing users -- so a non-JSON answer is recommended.

EDIT2:  I just need to Target Android 4.1+ at the moment.

Comment: if you want to maintain minSdk version , maybe it's not problem to use deprecated methods.

Comment: Well I only need to target Android 4.1+ at the moment, if there is a one solution that fits all, and does not use deprecated stuff, that is what I would like to do.  Also, I am OCD, I don't like lines going thru my code telling me things are deprecated..

Comment: You can use annotations like `@SuppressLint` or ` @TargetApi(22)` to use newer library, and  use `@suppresswarnings` to clear that warnints. I think that would't be bad decision.

Comment: I know, I know,  I don't like those either.  :D   Usually something is deprecated for a reason, so I would like to update when possible.  And in this case, Google recommended this change like 3 years ago.

Comment: I also hate the tricking with code like this, but sometimes it's inevitable. Hope you find your answer, good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Here is parameter stuff:

```
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String s = "unit_type=" + URLEncoder.encode(MainActivity.distance_units, charset);
        s += "&long=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(MainActivity.mLongitude), charset);
        s += "&lat=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(MainActivity.mLatitude), charset);
        s += "&user_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(MyndQuest.userId), charset);

        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(s.getBytes().length);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(s);
        out.close();
```