# httpurlConnection with httpParams in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, inetaddress, http-parameters

I'm trying to post a file from local to another platform over a switch. When i do it with DefaultHttpClient there is no problem.

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName(interfaceIp));
DefaultHttpClient httpClientPost = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

But i have to do it with HttpURLConnection. Is there a way to do this?

for example:

```
httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(myHttpParams);
```

here is my HttpUrlConn codes

```
            url = new URL(baseUrl+"/html/uploadimage.cgi");
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +"----WebKitFormBoundary"+boundary);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "192.168.1.1");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "16551361");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Origin", "http://192.168.1.1");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Referer", baseUrl + "/html/advance.html");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");

            String cookie =  "Username="+ username +"; " +
                    "Password="+ cyreptedPassword +"; Language=tk; " +
                    "username="+ username +"; " +
                    "SessionID_R3="+ sessionID +"; activeMenuID=maintain_settings; activeSubmenuID=device_mngt";

            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(9999*9999999);
            outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"), true);
```

thanks for all.

Comment: this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29381874/3138755

Comment: thanks for replay but it's not useful for me, because i will file upload over the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpUrlConnection does not use http params, but it uses proxy.

[here](https://enbiyakocbiyik.wordpress.com/2016/02/23/httpurlconnection-kullanarak-file-upload-islemi/) is some information about httpUrlConnection example.